# What's wrong with this line of code?

Tags: errors

I have this code and it is not compiling. What's wrong whit it?

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

<<\text{Units$\grave{ }$}\\
\text{ppgfttoPSI}=0.0519481;

Dado PI e PO, rint e rext, faz o c{\' a}lculo da tens{\~ a}o radial e tangencial

\text{ComputeRadialAndTangetialStress}[\text{r$\_$},\text{ri$\_$},\text{re$\_$},\text{PI$\_$},\text{PO$\_$}]\text{:=}\text{Block}[\{\text{sigr},\text{sigtheta}\},\\
\text{sigr}=(\text{PI} (r{}^{\wedge}2-\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2) \text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2+\text{PO} \text{re}{}^{\wedge}2 (-r{}^{\wedge}2+\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2))/(r{}^{\wedge}2
(\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2));\\
\text{sigtheta}=(\text{PI}(r{}^{\wedge}2+\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2) \text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{PO} \text{re}{}^{\wedge}2 (r{}^{\wedge}2+\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2))/(r{}^{\wedge}2
(\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2));\\
\{\text{sigr},\text{sigtheta}\}\text{//}N\\
];


\end{document}
```

Comment: That one line on its own is not a complete document so will give multiple errors if anyone tries it, please make a complete small document that generates the error that you are asking about.

Comment: If you load `amsmath` and insert the expression inside `$ $` for example, it should work.

Comment: `\text` should be used in math mode. I think that you need some verbatim, to insert program codes.

Comment: @Sigur and @David Carlisle, i have edited the code. The original code is huge and i put just a small part of it. The code ii automatilly generated by Mathematica. And every line that appears a power expression gives error. I think the problem is with `\wedge`...

Comment: mathematica presumably just generates a fragment of math markupo, as Sigur says you need to put it in math mode eg with `$` also the markup `{\' a}` is wrong, it should  be `\'{a}` or simpler with `inputenc` package just á

Comment: I guess that at Wolfram they aren't much interested in TeX output, seen what rubbish code their converters produce. It's hard to tell what's not wrong, because all is.

Comment: It'll be easier if you tell us what you're trying to write (a screenshot will do) and we tell you how.

Comment: I'm writing a report and i want to include the code in it. But i'will do it by hand. I appreciate all the help, but i give up of generating a tex code automatically with Mathematica. As said by @egreg the automatic generated code is terrible.

Comment: "it is not compiling" - show us the error message!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to improve such horrible code without essentially rewriting it from scratch. Even adding `$` at appropriate spots produces nothing really similar to typeset output, but just letters and symbols one next to each other without any clue for understanding the code.

```
$<<\text{Units$\grave{ }$}\\
\text{ppgfttoPSI}=0.0519481;$

Dado PI e PO, rint e rext, faz o c{\' a}lculo da tens{\~ a}o radial e tangencial

$\text{ComputeRadialAndTangetialStress}[\text{r$\_$},\text{ri$\_$},\text{re$\_$},\text{PI$\_$},\t$
\text{sigr}=(\text{PI} (r{}^{\wedge}2-\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2) \text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2+\text{PO} \tex$
(\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2));\\
\text{sigtheta}=(\text{PI}(r{}^{\wedge}2+\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2) \text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{PO} \$
(\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2));\\
\{\text{sigr},\text{sigtheta}\}\text{//}N\\
];$
```

[image]

Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
<<Units`
ppgfttoPSI=0.0519481;

Dado PI e PO, rint e rext, faz o cálculo
da tensão radial e tangencial

ComputeRadialAndTangetialStress}[r_,ri_,re_,PI_,PO_]:=
Block[{sigr,sigtheta},
  sigr=PI(r^2-re^2) ri^2+PO re^2 (-r^2+ri^2))/(r^2(re^2-ri^2));
  sigtheta=(PI(r^2+re^2) ri^2-PO re^2 (r^2+ri^2))/(r^2(re^2-ri^2));
  {sigr,sigtheta}//N
];
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

might be better and even simpler to copy and paste.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This tex code is still pretty poor but runs without error and may be a start towards hand correcting the generated code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

<<\text{Units$\grave{ }$}\\
\text{ppgfttoPSI}=0.0519481;

Dado PI e PO, rint e rext, faz o c\'{a}lculo da tens\~{a}o radial e tangencial

\begin{multline}
\text{ComputeRadialAndTangetialStress}[\text{r$\_$},\text{ri$\_$},\text{re$\_$},\text{PI$\_$},\text{PO$\_$}]\text{:=}\\
\text{Block}[\{\text{sigr},\text{sigtheta}\},\\
\text{sigr}=(\text{PI} (r{}^{\wedge}2-\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2) \text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2+\text{PO} \text{re}{}^{\wedge}2 (-r{}^{\wedge}2+\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2))/(r{}^{\wedge}2
(\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2));\\
\text{sigtheta}=(\text{PI}(r{}^{\wedge}2+\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2) \text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{PO} \text{re}{}^{\wedge}2 (r{}^{\wedge}2+\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2))/(r{}^{\wedge}2
(\text{re}{}^{\wedge}2-\text{ri}{}^{\wedge}2));\\
\{\text{sigr},\text{sigtheta}\}\text{//}N\\
];
\end{multline}


\end{document}
```